# MS SQL Server, Create and update a table based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I want to try and create a boolean table with the same structure as another table. I know how to create the table but my issue is the updating.

Lets say i have the table *A1* with 10 columns with different attributes for a person such as, height, run speed, name, hair colour etc.

I then want to be able to modifiy this table by either removing or adding columns to table *A1* and these updates apply to my other column *B1* so it has the same columns but a boolean value (the boolean value is not based on A1).

My first question is if it's doable.

My second is: Will the updates be super ineffecient for lets say 200-300 records.

(I could probably create an external program that reads the table and manually removes and adds columns via ADD/DROP sql statements, but i was hoping there was a more dynamic/efficent solution)

Comment: I am not fully following your example compeletely but updating one table base on another is very standard functionality if you are talking about updating rows.  Synchronizing columns is easy as well but not as standard.  Are you wanting this to happen automatically or based on when another action occurs? 200-300 records unless they are huge fields shouldn't matter as much on efficiency as any changes to a table(s) like that should be fast.

Comment: The Table A1 has e.g. Name, Height, Weight, Hair color.

The Table B1 then has the columns: Name, Height, Weight, Hair color.

If i then later on Add a column to A1, like Nationality i want B2 to have also add the column Nationality but as a a Boolean type value

Comment: What will the boolean value be?  do you need this automatically?  If you are trying to do change tracking you could look into "change tracking in sql server which would track it for you.  I guess depending on use their may be different solutions/suggestions.  Also are you allowed to write db triggers? @Mike's answer below also has a valid point of organizing it in rows rather than columns....

Comment: The boolean table is read from an application and then gives the user the availability to change the boolean value to true or false for each row + column. The original table is handled by a separate application that has the option to create or remove a column if needed. What i really want is to create a table that adapts to the original by using the the same amount of columns and their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want, as another answer posted, is EAV schema "entity - attribute - value". This allows you to dynamically add new attributes without changing any physical table schema. It is also horrible for performance (but with only a few hundred entities it shouldn't be too bad).

Another equally ugly solution is to add as many columns as you think you'll ever need, named Attribute_1, Attribute_2, etc. Then you have a lookup table which allows you to map attributes to their definitions.

This is less flexible than the EAV schema, but allows you to index on specific attributes so that your queries are a little more performant.

Another solution would be to use XML data types to hold the attributes and values. SQL Server has built-in functionality for XML data, while it's not as easy to use as normal SQL, it does work quite well.

Comment: How would the performance of a EAV schema be compared to adding and subtracting columns?

Haven't worked much with XML but i'll give it a rough sketch to see what i can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add and subtract columns to the table. I would suggest that you have a table with the fixed attributes. Then have another table which stores additional attributes (the names of the columns) then a third table which holds the id of the person, the is off the attribute and the value of the attribute.

For example the user table :

```
UserId
Firstname
Surname
```

The attribute table

```
AttrId
AttrName
```

The UserAttribute table:

```
UserId  
AttrId 
AttrValue
```

For this to answer your question you could have two sets of these tables but the AttrValue would be boolean for the second table.

An intermediate option is to go for multiple spare columns in the table and use the attribute table to store a column name and a boolean to indicate if the column is in use

Comment: I understand the logic behind it but my problem with this is that the structure is harder to read and i'm not sure if it would be quicker than just removing or adding columns. I'll probably settle with something similar if i can't find some kind of "child" from "parent"  table functionality.